# Nested Loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I am learning Python Loops. In code below, I am not able to get desired output.

I want to separate two nested-list values into two seperate lines
Code:

```
list_of_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
    for list1 in list_of_list:
        print (list1)
        for x in list1:
            print (x)
```

Desired Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

My Current output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Please give advice on how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: you don't need the second print

Comment: Or the second loop, in fact.

Comment: `for x in list1: print (x)` is not needed..

Answer (score 2):

#### Several ways:

**1. `join`**

Do:

```
print('\n'.join([str(i) for i in list_of_list]))
```

**2. `list comprehension`**

Do:

```
[print(i) for i in list_of_list]
```

**3. `for-loop`**

Do:

```
for i in list_of_list:
    print(i)
```

#### All Output:

**This:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

As desired

**To explain why yours is not working:**

- Because too many loops, just need one loop
- The outer loop is enough for getting desired, you have nested loops so first loop (is what i mean by outer loop)

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for list1 in list_of_list:
    print (list1) #This print gives the desired output & as mentioned in the comment the second print isn't required
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in 1 line:

```
[print(l) for l in list_of_list]
```

which translate to:

```
for l in list_of_list:
    print(l)
```

Which is what you want.